# Testing Nancy module with nUnit fails assert when testing HttpStatusCode

Tags: unit-testing, enums, nunit, nancy

I'm trying to write tests for a Nancy project. I've stripped my test back to bare basics but am still getting a seemingly bizarre result.

The module:

```
public class HomeModule : BaseModule
{
    public HomeModule(IUserMapper mapper)
    {
        Get["/"] = "Hello, world!";
    }
}
```

The test:

```
[Test]
public void Home_Index_should_return_response_OK()
{
    var result = GetBrowser().Get("/", with => with.HttpRequest());

    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, result.StatusCode);
}
```

The assert fails with this message:

> Expected: OK
>     But was:  OK

**WTF?** Both results are of type `HttpStatusCode` and value "OK". If I add `.GetValue()` or `.ToString()` to them both, the assert passes but it feels vary *hack-y* and something something 'code smell'.

At first I thought it might be a quirk with nUnit and testing enums but when I try something like this:

```
var value = ActionTargets.Suite;
Assert.AreEqual(ActionTargets.Suite,value);
```

it passes fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Argggh.... I've been ReShafted..

I just found this at the top of the file which I'm certain I didn't put there myself.

```
using HttpStatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode;
```

Lesson to be learned here: don't blindly rely on tooling to do your thinking for you.

Comment: Thanks for the cautionary tale.  You can uncheck "Allow the alias using directive" under ReSharper options to keep this from happening.